# Error running any Java web project on my notebook

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets

when I try to run any java web project I get this error. BUT this only happens on my notebook. I've tried on other desktop and other notebook on the same order and everything works well there but to work I only have my notebook so can only see what is the problem please?

```
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\proXPN\bin
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:prac09-struts2-ejem02-v2' did not find a matching property.
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 731 ms
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:38 PM org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer init
INFO: Initializing Tiles2 container. . .
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:38 PM org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer initializeDefinitionsFactory
INFO: Tiles2 container initialization complete.
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:38 PM org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess setContainer
INFO: Publishing TilesContext for context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Could not find or error in org/apache/struts2/default.properties - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.config.DefaultPropertiesProvider.register(DefaultPropertiesProvider.java:46)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:131)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5235)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Could not load org/apache/struts2/default.properties:java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\braulio\FIA (The system cannot find the file specified) - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.config.PropertiesSettings.<init>(PropertiesSettings.java:73)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.DefaultPropertiesProvider.register(DefaultPropertiesProvider.java:44)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\braulio\FIA (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.PropertiesSettings.<init>(PropertiesSettings.java:70)
    ... 18 more
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/prac09-struts2-ejem02-v2] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:38 PM org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess setContainer
INFO: Removing TilesContext for context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2011 12:47:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1880 ms
```

I'm trying struts2 on eclipse helios 64-bit with tomcat 7.0 and mysql server 5.0

Please tell me if it is necessary any further information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\braulio\FIA (The system cannot find the file specified)` Does that file exist on the computers that DO work? Could be a pattern there.

Comment: @Braulio: this isn't a programming question, it's probably going to be migrated.

Answer (score 2):

> C:\Users\braulio\FIA (The system
>   cannot find the file specified)

Please make sure if this file is in the correct location.

This is the only error i can guess from the log.

Answer (score 1):

looks like it cannot find the struts config file.

maybe install struts on the machine again?